# Need help removing KitchenAid range's control panel

Tags: glass-top-range

I have a kerc700LBL0 KitchenAid electric range (glass top).  The oven temperature on the display gets pretty dim.  From what I've read online, it's the control board (capacitors).  I'm having trouble getting the control panel (the glass touch panel) off so I can get to the electronics underneath (the control board).  I removed three screws and the front now lifts up a bit, but something in the back is holding it.  It could be some clips, or maybe screws, or maybe I just need to pull harder (don't know).  I called KitchenAid and they couldn't tell me.  Anyone know how this comes off?

This is a a similar model (to show you where the control panel is:

[image]

This is a the control panel:

[image]

Here is a [parts diagram](https://www.repairclinic.com/ProductDetail/621306?tab=diagrams#/Whirlpool/KERC700LBL0/06_-_CONTROL_PANEL%2C_OPTIONAL/KERC700LBL0/06_-_CONTROL_PANEL%2C_OPTIONAL_(KERC700LBL0)/y) that doesn't show any screws in the back, but I'm not sure how much I can trust it.

One website said this model is made by Whirlpool, but I haven't confirmed it (nor do I have any further information like model number(s)).

Thanks!

Comment: Whirlpool & Kitchenaid are one company. But knowing that doesn't solve your problem - unless you can find a very similar Whirlpool model with more detailed instructions.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured this out.  The rear is kind of held on with a loose "clip".  First, clean out all the gunk that accumulates in the crack between the display/touch panel and the glass top (I used a thin putty knife).  I think that "glues the back on" which was part of my problem.  Then, (after you remove the three screws), just lift the front display up like the back is hinged.  You may need to pull forward just a bit after you pull it up an inch or so.  As the front lifts up, the back eventually pulls away.  (There's very little force holding the back).